# JsQRCode reader not working properly

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, qr-code

I am using [JSQRCode](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode) JS library to decode QR codes.
I found that it works just fine if I take pictures of the QR code from really close.

If I take the picture from a bit farther it is not able to decode the code.

NOTE: The code-decoding library is used within a Sencha Touch 2 app. The picture is taken using the Ext.device.Camera API that gives access to the phone camera.

Has anybody had similar problems?
Any possible solution or alternative way to reach the goal (taking picture + QR decoding)?

Any suggestion/comment is very appreciated!
Thank you very much!

Here is the code I'm running:

```
Ext.device.Camera.capture({
success: function(fileURI) {
        // reassigning for test purposes
        //fileURI = './resources/images/qrTemp.png';

        console.log('Camera Success');
    var imageView = Ext.getCmp('cameraImg');
    imageView.setSrc(fileURI);

        qrcode.decode(fileURI);
},
failure: function() {
    console.log('Camera failure');
},
quality: 100,
source: 'camera'

}, /*scope*/ this, /*destination*/ 'file', /*encoding*/ 'png');

...

qrcode.callback = function(data){
window.alert('QRCode callback: '+ data);
};
```

UPDATE: just found out the problem is that the camera API from sencha touch is returning a very small image (although supposed to return a bigger one), so the code reader lib is not able to decode!
Anyone has faced this Sencha Touch problem?